# Select a site to pin spinner shows wrong info

Tags: bug, android-app

When choosing which sites to pin to show in the left drawer, sometimes the list of suggestions shows inaccurate suggestions or doesn't show up.

To reproduce, open the left drawer, then click the "YOUR SITES          EDIT" row (below "Feed").
(1) Tap the "Select a site to pin" spinner's downward facing triangle.
(b) The list of suggestions appears and the triangle now points upwards.
(2) Click the triangle again.
(b) The suggestions list disappears.

Seen behavior:
The triangle stays pointing upwards.
(3a) Clicking the triangle again has no effect.

Expected behavior:
When the list disappears (b) the triangle should then point downwards.
(3b) Clicking the triangle again should show the list again.

Note: to recover from this modifying the text on the spinner's textbox shows the dropdown list again.

Comment: Seems to be (1) duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219656/site-selection-drop-down-is-locked-up-when-choosing-sites-to-pin?rq=1 and also (2) already solved :)