# Site selection drop-down is locked up when choosing sites to pin

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

**Description:**  The drop-down list, when trying to select additional Stack Exchange sites to pin to the nav drawer, does not act correctly and gets stuck a locked (up) position.

**How to reproduce the error:**

1. Open the Stack Exchange app and tap on the nav drawer
2. Tap "Edit" on the right side of the "Your Sites" header
3. Tap the drop-down next to the "Select a site to pin" (triangle icon)
4. Tap the same triangle icon button again to close the drop down
5. You are now unable to re-open the drop down to pin additional sites.

**Expected Output:** The drop-down drawable (triangle icon) should change
onClick and toggle the full Stack Exchange site list visibility.

**Actual Output:** The drop-down drawable (triangle icon) does not match the
context and the list is locked in the invisible state.

As a side note when fixing this bug, I also found that the state of the
drop-down is not saved when using the back button or using the nav drawer to
go to other parts of the app. Please make sure you save the state of the
drawable and the visibility of the list.

I'm using a VZW Moto X running Android 4.4, completely stock. I hope this
helps.

Comment: -1: I have no phone +1: bug report +1: formatting

Comment: Thanks for the *excellent* report, looking into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report! The button is now correctly tappable as many times as you want as of version 1.0.7.